# How to change the color of the just drawed Shape(ActionScript)

Tags: flash, actionscript

i have drawed some figure(circle, rectangle or just a line) and after that i want to change they color without drawing another figure overlaying those, is that possible?

```
graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 1);
graphics.drawCircle(70, 67, 2);
graphics.drawCircle(90, 67, 2);
graphics.endFill();
```

after this code is possible to change the color of those circles? lets say some time later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is and it isn't.  Once you draw that shape it becomes baked into the draw buffer for that frame. If you've drawn it to the main frame-buffer, that's it, no changies.  What you CAN do is draw it to a separate instance of a `Sprite` or `MovieClip` and use [`ColorTransform`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html).

```
var mc:MovieClip=new MovieClip();

mc.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 1);
mc.graphics.drawCircle(70, 67, 2);
mc.graphics.drawCircle(90, 67, 2);
mc.graphics.endFill();
```

and later:

```
var c:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
c.color = (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
mc.transform.colorTransform = c;
```

Putting your shape in a `MovieClip` also has the advantage of not having to redraw it on every frame manually (clearing the normal frame-buffer won't clear the `MovieClip`'s) and also means you can move it around easily with `mc.x` and `mc.y`.

Just out of curiosity, why can't you set the color when it's drawn?

Comment: i really didn't knowed about the transform object of movieClip and the colorTransform method i will try them, thank you for this answer, before i was redrawing those pixels and that is the only way i knowed up to this moment